# How to show Visual Studio Online build task Write-Verbose statements?

Tags: powershell, build, azure-devops

Many Visual Studio Online (VSO) [build tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks) use [Write-Verbose](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849951.aspx) for debugging purposes as seen in [this example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/MSBuild/MSBuild.ps1), but how do you turn Write-Verbose on so that the debug statements appear in the output logs?

Comment: Usually the way you do this in PowerShell is to either invoke the command with `-Verbose` or set the variable  `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'`.

Comment: Since the script has `params`, it gets an automatic `CmdletBinding`, so `-Verbose` should work as @KeithHill said.

Comment: Thank you @KeithHill and @Eris.  First I tried with `-Verbose` and no change.  Then I added `[CmdletBinding()]` ahead of `param()` in the PowerShell script and the Verbose messages started printing.

Comment: ... more info, adding `[CmdletBinding()]` is only possible when it is a PowerShell script that I write.  There are several dozen Microsoft provided tasks that neither have `[CmdletBinding()]` nor do they have the ability to pass an argument of `-Verbose` to the executing PowerShell script.  I am looking for a general way to set the verbosity that will work across all scripts either written by Microsoft or myself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get verbose and debug statements to show up in the log you simply need to add the System.Debug variable to the variables on your definition.

Comment: Thank you. Adding a variable with the name "system.debug" and the value of "true" to my build variables worked and I can now see the Write-Verbose statements from the PowerShell task scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Use `Write-Verbose "Text" -Verbose` inside your script
2. Assign build variable `system.debug` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

(Just moving comments to an answer)

Since the script has params, but does not have `CmdletBinding`, nor a `[Parameter(...)]` then `-Verbose` is not honored.

Solution: Add `[CmdletBinding()]` before the `params` or add a `[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` or something similar to one or more of the individual parameter variables.

From [about_parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx]):

> All attributes are optional. However, if you omit the CmdletBinding
>       attribute, then to be recognized as an advanced function, the function
>       must include the Parameter attribute.

[about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847872.aspx) has more information on the abilities bestowed upon cmdlets.